# How do I convert this javascript line to c#?

Tags: c#, javascript, file-conversion

I understand the first part of the line, but I'm not sure what the part after the || does. Can anyone tell me how to convert this line to c#?

```
var g = grid[iy * gw + ix] || [];
```

Original source is here.
http://www.dhteumeuleu.com/aqualibrium/source

Answer (score 2):

It's the logical or, but basically equivalent to C#'s [null-coalescing operator `??`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).  It resolves to the left, or the right if the left is `false`.

The one caveat is that, because of Javascript's dynamic typing, the situation isn't as clear-cut as in C#.  The `||` forces the left-hand value to be converted to a bool, and there are various values that will end up being converted to `false`.  For example, Javascript will evaluate all these as "other":

```
* false || 'other';
* 0 || 'other';
* '' || 'other';
* undefined || 'other';
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented || is equivalent to c#'s to the coalesce operator ??. And [] is an empty array.

In this case `grid` is an array of arrays of Particles. The C# equivalent code would be:

```
// Particle[][] grid = ...

Particle[] g = grid[iy * gw + ix] ?? new Particle[];
```